# How to handle reviews on answers of a questions that are put on hold?

Tags: discussion

Recently I was reviewing `low quality posts` and spotted a "typical" `Link only answer`. It was not like the one's with just a link, but just a little more context that you could google in case the link is dead.

I always check the link if it makes any sense in the context of the question; it did and it was a nice article but I also noticed that the question was put `on hold`.

With relatively new users I normally I would actively encourage them to grab the essential parts from the article and put it in the question. But in this case, since the question was put `on hold` this wouldn't lead to any `reward` for the effort (in my opinion the "reward system" is a major success factor of this site).

The answer was well received by the way, the up-vote count was relatively high, so it truly helped some people.

So I was in this dilemma of what to do:

- *use the `link only` and recommend deletion?* This would lead to deletion of the question although it could be salved and scored good.
- *Guide the user to improve his/her answer?* This would not lead to a "reward"-satisfaction at the users side.
- *Mark as `Looks OK`?* This seems to violate the policy of this site.

I `skipped` the particular review, but it kept me wondering...

So in general:

How to handle reviews on answers of a question that's put on hold?

Answer (score 3):

If the "answer" contains only instruction, how to find something in google, it's still technically *link-only answer*, because it doesn't answer the question directly, but refers to external resources.

If the question is on hold, it means that it probably is not good fit for Q&A anyway. The answer was already borderline, combined with low quality of the question it makes it hardly valuable.

I'd simply vote to delete it anyway.